# compare two columns in PostgreSQL show only highest value

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my table
I'm trying to find in which urban area having high girls to boys ratio.
Thank you for helping me in advance.

```
| urban | allgirls | allboys |
| :---- | :------: | :-----: |
| Ran   | 100      | 120     |
| Ran   | 110      | 105     |
| dhanr | 80       | 73      |
| dhanr | 140      | 80      |
| mohan | 180      | 73      |
| mohan | 25       | 26      |
```

This is the query I used, but I did not get the expected results

```
SELECT urban, Max(allboys) as high_girls,Max(allgirls) as high_boys
from table_urban group by urban
```

Expected results

```
| urban | allgirls | allboys |
| :---- | :------: | :-----: |
| dhar  | 220      | 153     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your example expected result doesn't seems correct because the girls to boys ratio is highest in "mohan" and not in "dhanr" - If what you are really looking for is the highest ratio and not the highest number of girls.

You need to first group and find the sum and then find the ratio (divide one with other) and get the first one.

```
select foo.urban as urban, foo.girls/foo.boys as ratio from (
SELECT urban, SUM(allboys) as boys, SUM(allgirls) as girls
FROM table_urban 
GROUP BY urban) as foo order by ratio desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT urban, SUM(allboys) boys, SUM(allgirls) girls
FROM table_urban 
GROUP BY urban
ORDER BY boys / girls -- or backward, "girls / boys"
LIMIT 1
```